# Shortening the WP-CLI install operation

Tags: permissions, php, curl, wordpress

WP-CLI is a Bash expansion that allows you to automate different operations in the popular CMS WordPress.

Given my environment setup script is already quite long (by means of lines), I've setted the WP-CLI installation directives in one line:

```
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar && chmod +x wp-cli.phar && mv wp-cli.phar /usr/local/bin/wp
```

Is there a way to further shorten it? Maybe with curl's ability to print files' content to `stdout` and the content's ability to be piped into `stdin`? This might save the `chmod` and the `mv` via permission preserving and redirection (`>`)?

Comment: Are you running into a length limitation somewhere? How far do you want to golf it at the expense of legibility and maintainability?

Comment: No, I just want to reduce horizontal scrolling as much as I can while reducing lines as much as I can, mainly for the comfortability while maintaining.

Comment: why the obsession with minimising line count?  unreadably long lines are far more of a problem than extra lines.  it's good programming practice to add linefeeds and whitespace for indentation to improve the readability of scripts.  e.g. insert a line feed and indent by a tab or 2 or 4 spaces after each `&&`.

Comment: I don't have that obsession. I consolidate data when asking and learn from the answers and others do too. Not always reducing the number of lines, or shortening lines, results in uncomfortable reading. Generally, when it does I find the way to cope with that. If there isn't I go back to the original phrasing.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/996802/further-automating-ubuntu-nginx-wordpress-server-environment-establishment-scrip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar -O /usr/local/bin/wp/wp-cli.phar && chmod +x wp-cli.phar
```

This way it removes the step of `mv`'ing the file.  I'm sure `curl` has an "output to" option if you don't want to use `wget` for some reason.

As @WEBjuju mentioned in his/her answer using a URL shortener could help just for overall length.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to shorten that line is to use a url shortener:

> curl -O http://bit . ly/2eoqKcf && chmod +x wp-cli.phar && mv wp-cli.phar /usr/local/bin/wp

*note we can't submit posts with bit.ly addresses in them, so remove the spaces in `bit . ly`*

Comment: `curl -O http://bit.ly/2eoqKcf && chmod +x wp-cli.phar && mv wp-cli.phar /usr/local/bin/wp/` fails: "No such file or directory"

Comment: Anyway, I thank you and I thumbed up. In the end I used a shortened URL as you suggested but I made the shortening with Google `goo.gl` URL shortening tool.